# Navegação via HTML ou Javascript

Tags: javascript, html5, seo

Venho trabalhando bastante com javascript e isso me faz usá-lo para quase tudo. Mas estou com uma dúvida.

Existe algum problema de semântica, indexação ou de resultados de pesquisas da minha página quando eu utilizo:

**HTML:** `<img class="teste" src="img.pjg">`

**Javascript/jQuery:** `$('.teste').click(() => window.location.href = 'pagina.html');`

Ao invés de usar:

**HTML:** `<a href="pagina.html"><img src="img.pjg"></a>`

Comment: Acredito que a segunda opção seja a melhor, é mais clara para o SEO. Além do mais, adicionar trigger pela class de um elemento para algo unico, como acessar uma determinada página, não é nada legal, use ID para isso. $('#teste1)....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sim, existem problemas de indexação ao usar javascript para os links.

Os mecanismos de busca navegam pelo site seguindo as âncoras e guardando o texto que foi utilizado nas mesmas. Se você usar navegação por javascript nem todos os indexadores terão inteligência suficiente para conseguir seguir os links da sua página, talvez o Google já tenha trabalhado em algo nesse sentido, mas o uso normal do link é muito mais garantido.

Em ordem do que é mais valioso para um mecanismo de busca, segue:

1) A url.  Ex: www.palavrachave.com ou www.seusite.com/palavrachave

2) O texto da âncora. Quanto mais lugares usando palavra-chave na âncora da página, mais relevante fica a url linkada. Se o link for uma imagem, use alt ou title.

Ex: Vários lugares linkando para `<a href="http://www.bolosdatiateteca.com">Tia Teteca - Bolos de aniversário</a>` numa busca por "**Bolos de aniversário**" é muito mais relevante que `<a href="http://www.bolosdatiateteca.com">bolosdatiateteca.com</a>`

3) O título da página.

4) O texto das tags h1, h2 e h3.

5) O texto dentro de parágrafos.

No seu caso:

HTML:

`<img class="teste" src="img.pjg">`

Javascript/jQuery:

`$('.teste').click(() => window.location.href = 'pagina.html');`

O indexador do site de busca pode nunca indexar esse link. Apenas se o indexador varrer também javascript procurando por fragmentos `location.href`.

HTML:

`<a href="pagina.html"><img src="img.pjg"></a>`

Nesse caso, você tem o link sendo indexado logo de cara. Ponha um alt na imagem e esse link se tornará mais relevante para mecanismos de busca.